# put sql data in java maps and then get value from rows

Tags: java, sql, dictionary, groovy, hashmap

I am putting the data into my map as

```java
Map getDataFromQuery(String query){
        def firstRow = sql.firstRow(query)
        return firstRow
```

but my sql query is giving me more than one row and I need to get values for specific columns. and I need make sure the row references stay intact.

ex: i need firstname, lastname,active status. for 50 people.

I cant change the sql query, only how the data is being stored and what values I can take from it.

Comment: If you're unable to change the query, could you show us how the data is currently being stored?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, that `sql` here is an instance of `groovy.sql.Sql`, your use
of `firstRow` restricts the result to just one row.  Use
[`rows`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#rows(groovy.lang.GString))
instead to fetch all rows.

Yet, it is usually more efficient to just ask the database what you
actually need instead of fetching "everything" and weed things out in
the application.  You maybe could use the original query as an
sub-query.